# How to Include Legend in Seurat DimHeatmap function

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, seurat

Is there a general way to include legends in Seurat graphs? For example, if my code is,

```
DimHeatmap(norm_data3, dims = 1, cells = 500, balanced = TRUE)
```

how can I include a legend with color corresponding to value of PCA component?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit vague, but you should set `fast = FALSE`:

> If true, use image to generate plots; faster than using ggplot2, but
> not customizable

Here is a reproducible example using the `pbmc_small` dataset from the `Seurat` pacakage:

```r
library(Seurat)
#> Warning: package 'Seurat' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Attaching SeuratObject
#> Attaching sp
data("pbmc_small")
DimHeatmap(pbmc_small, dims = 1, cells = 500, balanced = TRUE, nfeatures = 4, fast = FALSE)
#> Warning: Requested number is larger than the number of available items (80).
#> Setting to 80.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to do this with ggplot also?

Comment: @AryanDugar, No problem! You mean creating a heatmap using `ggplot`?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I just read that setting ''' fast = false ''' makes it use ggplot2. I also wanted to ask more broadly, is there a general way to customize plots (so that we can adjust their titles and legends) in Seurat? Something like calling a function that creates a plot, and then doing ''' + geom_raster ''' ...? I understand if this might be suitable as another question, but I wanted to check with you anyway!